# How to remove google captcha from curl request?

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I am trying to **scrape** data from one website. But the problem is when i send CURL request google recaptcha is shown every time.

How i can remove this security check.

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://www.zillow.com/browse/homes/ca/';

$data = array(
    'secret' => "my-secret",
    'response' => "my-response"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result); 
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Comment: You can't remove that security check. You could potentially break it and make it believe your code is human, but I'm quite sure Google will patch that soon if you managed. However it seems Zillow has API, so why not use that? https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm

Answer (score 2):

**This is not possible** (at least not by ease)

The usecase for reCAPTCHA is to exactly prohibit what are you doing.
However some sites are only requesting reCAPTCHA when no user agent header was sent.
Try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
));
```

This will let the site think you are using Firefox 47 on Windows 7